# get implementing class for interface by specifying overloading method parameters Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, factory-pattern

I am not sure there is an easy way to explain my question so im just gonna share some code:

i have an interface:

**SOURCE** could be an xml object, json object etc...

**TARGET** is my final data object that i am happy to use in my code

```
public interface Populator<SOURCE, TARGET>{
   void populate(SOURCE source, TARGET target);
}
```

I have a number of implementing classes, here is a couple:

```
public  class XMLPopulator<SOURCE extends XMLDocument, TARGET extends StadardisedData> implements Populator<SOURCE, TARGET>{

    @Override
    public void populate(SOURCE source, TARGET target){
       target.setName(source.getName);
    }
```

And one more example of an implementing class:

```
public  class JSONPopulator<SOURCE extends JSONDocument, TARGET extends StadardisedData> implements Populator<SOURCE, TARGET>{

    @Override
    public void populate(SOURCE source, TARGET target){
       target.setName(source.getName);
    }
```

Okay so the above allows me to get a my StadardisedData object filled, which could consist of data from different sources, i.e xml and JSON, (just to give you some background on why i am doing this:  i have a number of different APIs where all provide me with data but the data needs to be standardised for me to use else where, which is why i am using this populator approach.

Now in Spring i have declared both of these populators like this:

```
<bean id="jsonPopulator" class="com.company.populators.JSONPopulator">
<bean id="xmlPopulator" class="com.company.populators.XMLPopulator">
```

What i need help with is that i want to dynamically pick a populator depending on my available values. See below:

```
public class MyClass{
   public static void main(String arg[]) { 
        List<Object> mixedValuesOfXMLandJSONDocuments = getDocuments();
        List<StadardisedData> stadardisedList = new ArrayList<StadardisedData>();
        for(Object document: mixedValuesOfXMLandJSONDocuments){
             StadardisedData stadardisedData = new StadardisedData();
            populator.populate(document, stadardisedData);//<- how would this populator be injected so the right populator gets used in Spring ?
            stadardisedList.add(stadardisedData);
        }
   }    
}
```

The above would execute the appropriate populators based on the values passed in

How could this be achieved in Spring ?

i have had a look at Springs *ServiceLocatorFactoryBean*, but couldn't work out how to use it for my example.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Looks like perhaps you just use the Spring `Converter` interface and a standard `ConversionService`.

Comment: Thanks Chrylis, but i cant use converters as converters return new object which is generated, my StadardisedData may already have some values but i am using populators to enrich it.  Also they are used through out the system can not change architecture to this extent unfortunately...

Comment: Then at a minimum look at how the `ConversionService` implements the lookup, since it seems you'd have the same logic, just acting on existing objects at the end.